# Why is the Barbecue Barcode library generating a different image from other Barcode generators?

Tags: coldfusion, barcode, barbecue

I am having a problem with the [Barbecue Barcode Library](http://barbecue.sourceforge.net/index.html). I am trying to  create a simple code128 barcode, but the image I get is different from what I get from other online (i.e. http://barcode-generator.org) and desktop (i.e. Zing) Barcode generators.

Here is the ColdFusion code I am using:

```
<cfscript>
    LOCAL.BarcodeData = "10047846";
    LOCAL.BarcodeFactory = CreateObject("java", "net.sourceforge.barbecue.BarcodeFactory");
    LOCAL.Barcode = LOCAL.BarCodeFactory.createCode128(LOCAL.BarcodeData);
    LOCAL.BarcodeImageHandler = CreateObject("java", "net.sourceforge.barbecue.BarcodeImageHandler");
    LOCAL.BarcodeBufferedImage = LOCAL.BarcodeImageHandler.getImage(LOCAL.Barcode);
    LOCAL.BarcodeImage = ImageNew(LOCAL.BarcodeBufferedImage);
    LOCAL.BarcodeImagePath =
        "C:\temp_\barcode-" & LOCAL.BarcodeData & ".jpg";
    ImageWrite(LOCAL.BarcodeImage, LOCAL.BarcodeImagePath, 1);
</cfscript>
<cfimage action="writeToBrowser" source="#LOCAL.BarcodeImagePath#" />
```

This outputs the following image:

[image: Barbecue-generated Barcode 10047846]

Yet, here is what I get from the Zing desktop program:

[image]

And here is what I get from barcode-generator.org:

[image]

Now, I have no issue with the sizing, scaling, etc. But, you can easily tell that the Barbecue-generated image is much different - simply look at the first several bars.

Why is this happening? Is this a Barbecue bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Why is this tagged with ColdFusion?

Comment: @ScottStroz Because I am using ColdFusion to call the library and generate the images.

Comment: '211214' pattern beginning the Barbeque-code is the START for CODE128B. The other two, '211232', are START for CODE128C.  Both are valid.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is the "answer", per se, but, when I changed the code to use the Code128C format, the image came out as expected. I just had to do some resizing to get it exactly the size I needed:

[image]

Code:

```
<cfscript>
    LOCAL.BarcodeData = "10047846";
    LOCAL.BarcodeFactory = CreateObject("java", "net.sourceforge.barbecue.BarcodeFactory");
    LOCAL.Barcode = LOCAL.BarCodeFactory.createCode128C(LOCAL.BarcodeData);
    LOCAL.Barcode.setDrawingText(false);
    LOCAL.Barcode.setDrawingQuietSection(false);
    LOCAL.Barcode.setBarWidth(1);
    LOCAL.Barcode.setBarHeight(30);
    LOCAL.BarcodeImageHandler = CreateObject("java", "net.sourceforge.barbecue.BarcodeImageHandler");
    LOCAL.BarcodeBufferedImage = LOCAL.BarcodeImageHandler.getImage(LOCAL.Barcode);
    LOCAL.BarcodeImage = ImageNew(LOCAL.BarcodeBufferedImage);
    LOCAL.BarcodeImagePath =
        "C:\temp_\barcode-" & LOCAL.BarcodeData & ".jpg";
    ImageWrite(LOCAL.BarcodeImage, LOCAL.BarcodeImagePath, 1);
</cfscript>
<cfimage action="writeToBrowser" source="#LOCAL.BarcodeImagePath#" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the bar width of your image is larger then the examples. Set the bar width to 1 px. by adding `LOCAL.Barcode.setBarWidth(1);`before you generate the barcode.

```
<cfscript>
  LOCAL.BarcodeData = "10047846";
  LOCAL.BarcodeFactory = CreateObject("java", "net.sourceforge.barbecue.BarcodeFactory");
  LOCAL.Barcode = LOCAL.BarCodeFactory.createCode128(LOCAL.BarcodeData);
  LOCAL.Barcode.setBarWidth(1); // decrease the width of the bars
  LOCAL.Barcode.setBarHeight(50); // if you want a taller barcode like the examples
  LOCAL.BarcodeImageHandler = CreateObject("java", "net.sourceforge.barbecue.BarcodeImageHandler");
  LOCAL.BarcodeBufferedImage = LOCAL.BarcodeImageHandler.getImage(LOCAL.Barcode);
  LOCAL.BarcodeImage = ImageNew(LOCAL.BarcodeBufferedImage);
  LOCAL.BarcodeImagePath = gettempDirectory()& "\barcode-" & LOCAL.BarcodeData & ".jpg";
ImageWrite(LOCAL.BarcodeImage, LOCAL.BarcodeImagePath, 1);
</cfscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

I scanned it with a barcode scanner and all three images read the same string "10047846".  For barcodes, I use CFBarbecue (http://cfbarbecue.riaforge.org/), a ColdFusion wrapper for Barbecue. Using the same string, below is the image I was able to generate using CFBarbecue.

[image]

Comment: I was using CFBarbecue as well, but I wanted to verify that it wasn't an issue with the CFC, so I wrote this simple app to try it.

Comment: that's good to know that it worked. I'm just trying to please the customer, for whom the barcode that I'm generating is NOT working.